# Data in the database {MySQL} will automatically update even without user who will going to open the page that contains the code of updating

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Good day!
Suppose that a user needs to perform an update to his account by opening a specific page in the website in every first day of the month, what If he/she forgot the update on that specific first day of month and I want my code to be designed as even though user forget to update, the data will be automatically updates in every first day of the month without the help of any, just a code that automatically runs on every first day of the month, anyone who could help with my problem?

for example:

```
<?php 
if (date("d") == 1){
//do some database queries here
}
?>
```

If that code is included in the page, I still need to wait for the page to open to perform the code, but In my case, I want it to be automatic, so even though user does not open the page, still the code above will perform.

Comment: What have you tried? I see no code here. SO doesn't magically write your code for you.

Comment: I wrote an example code. I just want to know the concept or any tools that can help me with my problem.

Comment: Try looking at cron jobs

Answer (score 0):

Well i think the only way is to put the code in the index but if the user doesnt open the website then you as an admin will need to do i manually

Comment: Is there any way to do it automatically? Without the help of any type of user?

Comment: Well i dont belive that you can do this but i have a crazy idea if you want to make it automaticlly you can just like a code in your index so that if any person or any user even if not the target user you go and update the target user

Comment: What i mean is that if you have user called "medo" that opens the website then just add a hidden code to update sams profile if this is the first day of the month

Comment: Run the code even if the target user isn't opening the websitr

Comment: What if the website has no visitor for that day, and what if unfortunately, that day will be the day where in the data is needed to be updates (just like in my example, first day of month.)?

Comment: Well can you give me a little background of what your website makes so i can help

Comment: It automatically adds an interest to the remaining balance of a user on every first day of the month.

Comment: Well let me tell you something when the user visits the website save the data of user visit on your website then when he logges in again get the current data and calculate how many months has past away since his last login and add the interset to his account

Answer (score 0):

Every time any page is loaded on your site, you can just call a procedure in another unit that checks the date and does what is required.  Just put it on every page.

If you want it to run even if no one logs in then google **cron**